# selecting elements javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a script that will notify you when someone is online on whatsapp web and i have this:

```
var onlineCheck = window.setInterval(function() {
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("emojitext ellipsify")[19];
if (y == null) {
  console.log("online notification failed");
} else {
  if (y.innerText === 'online') {
   new Notification("contact is online");
   window.clearInterval(onlineCheck);
}
}
},1000);
```

now the problem is that i'm selecting an element by the class "`emojitext ellipsify`" th 19th and if someone texts me another element with the class "`emojitext ellipsify`" will be made and the 19th won't be the status anymore, so i want to know if i can select an element with the same method from css which is : `element>element`
like this (`div#main>header.pane-header pane-chat-header>div.chat-body>div.chat-status ellipsify>span.emojitext ellipsify`)
or any other possible way.

```js
var onlineCheck = window.setInterval(function() {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("emojitext ellipsify")[19];
  if (y == null) {
    console.log("online notification failed");
  } else {
    if (y.innerText === 'online') {
      new Notification("contact is online");
      window.clearInterval(onlineCheck);
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<header class="pane-header pane-chat-header">
  <div class="chat-avatar">
    <div class="avatar icon-user-default" style="*somestyle*">
      <div class="avatar-body">
        <img src="*srcpath*" class="avatar-image is-loaded">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-body">
    <div class="chat-main">
      <h2 class="chat-title" dir="auto">
<span class="emojitext ellipsify" title="*person'sname*"><!-- react-text: 3216 -->*person'sname*<!-- /react-text --></span>
</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-status ellipsify">
      <span class="emojitext ellipsify" title="typing…"><!-- react-text: 3219 -->*the info that i need to get(typing…)*<!-- /react-text --></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pane-chat-controls">
    <div class="menu menu-horizontal">
      <div class="menu-item">
        <button class="icon icon-search-alt" title="Search…"></button>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-item">
        <button class="icon icon-clip" title="Attach"></button>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-item">
        <button class="icon icon-menu" title="Menu"></button>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Are you trying to select the last element with the classes`.emojitext` and `.ellipsify`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: the class is called (.emojitext ellipsify) so it's one class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is `document.querySelectorAll`

With that function, you can select elements with a selector, the same used with css. So, you could do this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".emojitext.ellipsify")
```

Or put a better selector, in order to get the desired elements, and not others.

Your example would be:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div#main>header.pane-header pane-chat-header>div.chat-body>div.chat-status ellipsify>span.emojitext.ellipsify")
```

Comment: thank you but i'm trying to get the innertext but it isn't working, i tried this
y = document.querySelectorAll("#main>header>div.chat-body>div.chat-status>span.emojitext .ellipsify");
console.log(y.innerText);
undefined
undefined

Comment: note: i'm using chrome's console to run this script

Comment: Remember that the call returns an array of elements. You should use `[0]` if you want to get the first one

Answer (score 2):

You could use JQuery, much simpler

```
$('parent > child')
```

https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: the problem is i'm running this script in chrome's console, will your method work?

Comment: Only if there is a page linked to that console that uses JQuery.

Comment: could you please show me how i should run the script
replace this line with your method:
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("emojitext ellipsify")[19];

Comment: The exact translation of that would be : var y = $('.emojitext, .ellipsify')[19];

Comment: I can't manage to get the innertext or innerhtml or even the title of the element i tried those:
var y = $('emojitext,ellipsify');
console.log(y.innerText);
-
var y = $('emojitext,ellipsify');
console.log(y.innerHTML);
-
var y = $('emojitext,ellipsify');
console.log(y.title);

Comment: it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at <anonymous>:2:14

Comment: JQuery has different functions to do that. You can do $('.emojitext, .ellipsify').html() to get the innerHTML and the .text() function returns the innerText. I also noticed that you forgot the dots before emojitext and ellipsify

Comment: I'm sorry i may be annoying you but it's not working i tried:
$('.emojitext, .ellipsify').html()
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).html is not a function
console.log($('.emojitext, .ellipsify')[19].html());
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined
console.log($('.emojitext, .ellipsify').html());
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).html is not a function

Comment: you can got to web.whatsapp.com and try it yourself by pressing on f12 to open the console

Comment: Yep, and that's because they are not using JQuery.